# measureText always return 0 on Android 4.0

Tags: android

when using

```
Paint.measureText(char[] buf, int start, int length)
```

on Android 4.0, it always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in Android 4.0 as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23337)

A workaround could be applied as below:

```
char[] tmpBuf = new char[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tmpBuf[i] = buf[start+i];
}
```

then use

```
paint.measureText(tmpBuf, 0, length);
```